# SQL Server cross database alias

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I'm trying to understand how I can use an alias to reference another database in the same instance, without having to use a hardcoded name.

The scenario is as below:

I have a data db with stores data, an audit db which keeps all changes made. for various reason, i want to keep the audit data in a separate database, not least because it can get quite large and for reporting purposes.

In the data db, I don't want to reference this by a hardcoded name but an alias so that in different environments, I don't have to change the name and various sp's to reference the new name.

for example:

```
mydevdata
mydevaudit
```

If a sp exists in `mydevdata` such as which calls the `mydevaudit`, I don't want to change the sp when I go to test where the db's may be called `mytestdata` and `mytestaudit`. Again, for various reasons, the database names can change, more to do with spaces an instances etc.

So if I had procedure in `mydevdata`:

```
proc A
begin

insert into mydevaudit.table.abc(somecol)
select 1

end
```

when I go to test, I don't want to be change the procedure to reference another name, (assume for sake of argument that happened)

Instead I am looking to do something like:

```
proc A
begin

insert into AUDITEBALIAS.table.abc(somecol)
select 1

end
```

I am interested in finding out how I could do something like that, and the pro's and cons.

Also, dymnamic SQL is not an option.

thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: please can you elaborate why "dymnamic SQL is not an option"

Answer (score 13):

You may be able to use [synonyms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx)

```
CREATE SYNONYM WholeTableAliasWithDBetc FOR TheDB.dbo.TheTable
```

This means all object references in the local DB are local to that DB, except for synonyms that hide the other database from you.

You can also use stored procedures *in* the audit DB. There is a 3rd form of [EXEC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) that is little used where you can parametrise the stored proc name

```
DECLARE @module_name_var varchar(100)
SET @module_name_var = 'mydevaudit.dbo.AuditProc'
--   SET @module_name_var = 'whatever.dbo.AuditProc'
EXEC @module_name_var @p1, @p2, ...
```

Obviously you can change module_name_var to use whatever DB you like

Answer (score 1):

I've just posted this to [How to create Sql Synonym or "Alias" for Database Name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444139/how-to-create-sql-synonym-or-alias-for-database-name) which is a workaround for the same situation:

There is a way to simulate this using a linked server. This assumes you have two SQL servers with the same set of databases one for development/test and one live.

1. Open SQL Server Management Studio **on your development/test server**
2. Right click Server Objects > Linked Servers
3. Select New Linked Server...
4. Select the General page
5. Specify **alias** name in Linked server field - this would normally be the name of your **live** server
6. Select SQL Native Client as the provider
7. Enter **sql_server** for Product Name
8. In Data Source specify the name of the **development** server
9. Add Security and Server Options to taste
10. Click OK

The above is for SQL Server 2005 but should be similar for 2008

Once you've done that you can write SQL like this:

```
SELECT * FROM liveservername.databasename.dbo.tablename
```

Now when your scripts are run on the development server with the linked server back to itself they will work correctly pulling data from the development server and when the exact same scripts are run on the live server they will work normally.