# Server.DataBase alias in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, alias

I've searched for this in quite a few areas, but haven't found a crystal clear answer to this.

I am working with multiple database servers and am consistently writing out [ServerName].[databasename].dbo.TableName.   I know you can alias a table, but I can't find a definite answer on server and database.

Is it possible to create an alias that allows me to call the alias rather than calling the entire [ServerName].[databasename].dbo.TableName?

As an example:
Server Name: SQL01
Database name: Client
Desired Alias: Client

Sample table name on SQL01.Client: Contact

From SQL02, can I call Client.Contact like `SELECT * FROM Client.Contact` rather than having to write `SELECT * FROM [SQL01].Client.dbo.Contact`?

Comment: take a look here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555646/sql-server-cross-database-alias

Comment: Where do you want this Alias to be visible from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already come across it, the key word you're looking for is "synonym", and the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187552%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) describes exactly the scenario you're interested in. So yes, it is possible.