# Alias name for database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, linked-server

I have a scenario to use Alias name to access database from SP, and I would like to know if there is any method to achieve this in SQL Server.

Since Linked Servers only allows Server objects and SYNONYM only allow object inside the database.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444139/how-to-create-sql-synonym-or-alias-for-database-name

Comment: [Using Synonyms (Database Engine)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187552%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Comment: As I said , my final query look like                              select * from MyAlias.dbo.tablename , and i am not using any front end application, so i may not able to control my connections.

Comment: Take a look at this [**link**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic654478-146-1.aspx)

Comment: I may need to write dynamic query i guess :(

Comment: There's no facility to allow alternate names to be used at the database level.

Comment: No. I think you should explain what you are trying to do. Maybe there is a better solution

Answer (score 0):

You can create a SYNONYM which includes the database name of the linked server ...

```
CREATE SYNONYM LinkedTableA
FOR DEVLINK.testdata.dbo.customer
```

and can then query ...

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.LinkedTableA
```